# Impulsive sources

Tags: circuit-analysis

According to my book in the circuit shown when an impulsive voltage having a strength of V0 is applied to a series connection of a resistor and an inductor, there is no voltage drop across the resistor and the impulsive voltage appears directly across L. The current that the inductor establishes then decays to zero in accordance with the natural response of the circuit.

I do not get it why the impulsive voltage doesn't result to a voltage drop across the resistor??

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvMZzM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The initial current through the inductor is 0, and the current through an inductor can't change instantaneously. Therefore, since the current through every part of a series circuit is the same everywhere, at the very beginning of the impulse, the current is zero, and zero current through a resistor means zero voltage drop.

Impulses ([Dirac delta functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function)) are tricky (i.e., nonintuitive), because they involve limits and infinities. The unit impulse is an infinitesimally-thin, infinitely-high pulse that has an area of exactly one. The scaling of such a pulse is in terms of its area, so if the vertical dimension is volts and the horizontal dimension is time, then the scale factor is in units of volt-seconds (not just volts).

The actual applied voltage is infinite, so if the current in the coil is a certain finite value after the pulse, then the voltage across the resistor is also a finite value. Therefore, *during the pulse*, the effect of the resistor's voltage drop is infinitesimal, because any finite value divided by an infinite value is effectively zero. The voltage pulse is effectively applied directly to the coil, which gives it an initial current of

$$\frac{V_0 \text{(volt-seconds)}}{L \text{(Henries)}} = i_0 \text{(amps)}$$

Since [Henries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_(unit)) are equivalent to volt-seconds per amp, the unit analysis works out. After the pulse is over, this current dissipates in the resistor with a time constant of \$\tau = L/R\$, giving an overall equation of

$$i(t) = i_0e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}} = \frac{V_0}{L}e^{-t\frac{R}{L}}$$

Comment: Dave: Thanks for the edit to my answer. I forgot that the syntax required double dollar signs, having not spent much time here or on math.se.

Comment: @Dave Thank you, but still it is hard to imagine that there is no current at t=0 but inductor sees a current change. Since there is a voltage drop across it whih is v=Ldi/dt.

Answer (score 0):

Initially, before the voltage pulse, the current in the inductor is zero. Let's say that the voltage pulse begins at T=0. For an inductor, we know that:

$$v = L \frac{di}{dt}$$

Additionally, we know that the voltage drop across the resistor is equal to IR. However, in our RL series circuit, the current is initially zero and has a finite rate of change (limited by V/L). As a result, we know that the drop across the resistor is equal to 0*R, hence zero volts.

When we consider times after T=0, we know that the voltage of the battery must equal the voltage drop of the resistor plus the voltage drop of the inductor, thus:

$$V_{batt} = IR + L \frac{dI}{dt}$$

Solving, we get that $$I(t) = \frac{V}{R}(1-e^{-tR/L})$$

Comment: No your answer is wrong, \$i(t)=\frac{V_0}{L} e^{-tR/L}\$

Comment: @MaryannEthan: No, hexafraction is right. The current starts out at zero and asymptotically approaches V/R, not the other way around. Your equation gives the derivative of the current \$(di/dt)\$.

Comment: @Dave The voltage source is an impulse so the current will go to zero eventually

Comment: Yes, you're right about that. hexafraction's answer is for a step response. The problem with your equation is that \$V_0/L\$ has units of amps/second rather than just amps.

Comment: I take that back -- \$V_0\$ has units of volt-seconds, so your equation is indeed correct. See the edit to my answer for a more complete explanation.

Comment: @MaryannEthan You're right; I misinterpreted the original question. I assumed step response as opposed to impulse of voltage.

Answer (score 0):

The current in an inductor can't change straight away (think 'electrical inertia'), so at the very instant the switch is closed, there is no current flowing in the inductor, no current means no voltage across the resistor. Now after the briefest instant, current will start to ramp up in the inductor, *now* there *will* be a voltage drop across the resistor as it's now got current flowing through it

Comment: I'm not sure what question you're answering. In *this* one, there is no switch, just an impulse voltage source.

Comment: the instant the switch is closed, the instant the voltage source is energised, t0 is just the marker for the instant something happens. But yes, I should have said "the instant the voltage impulse is applied to the circuit"

Answer (score 0):

Probably in non math but live easy model you could imagine a sine source at 1 GHz instead of a delta generator. The current in the coil will be zero because L impedance is infinite at high frequency so voltage drop in R will be 0.