# Draw the graph of differential of the following graph

Tags: signal-theory

[image]

Is is like this? I think there should be impulse signal also in the graph am i doing wrong? 
[image]

Comment: Remember the limit theorem for the derivative. At \$x=-3\$, \$\lim\limits_{h \to 0+}\frac{f\left(x+h\right)-f\left(x\right)}{h}\ne \lim\limits_{h \to 0-}\frac{f\left(x+h\right)-f\left(x\right)}{h}\$. So it's continuous but not differentiable at \$x=-3\$. This idea applies in a few other places there (which include jump discontinuities presenting still more difficulties.)

Answer (score 0):

Your graph looks fine.

And you're right — wherever there's a discontinuity in the original graph, there will be an impulse in the derivative. Perhaps that's something the instructor is overlooking in this particular exercise.

Comment: Do i have to represent the impulse in derivative graph? If so how will i represent it?

Comment: It's usually shown as an arrow pointing either up or down from the horizontal axis, with a number next to it that represents its area. (See [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/231576/11683) for some general discussion about impulses.)